# How to write a SQL where condition efficiently?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following very large (~ 10e8 records) table (`table`):

```
+--------------------------------+
|      id      order       value |
+--------------------------------+
|      PK       int         int  |
|       1        1           1   |
|       2        2           5   |
|       3        2               |
|       4        2           0   |
+--------------------------------+
```

As you can see, the value column can contain only non-negative integers or null. Now, I need to write a query returning orders which don't have a `value > 0` (i.e. `order = 2` doesn't hold the condition, because there's the record with `value = 5`).

The ***inverse query*** is simple:

```
SELECT order
FROM table
WHERE value > 0
```

The performance of the query is satisfactory for me.

But we can't quite write

```
SELECT order
FROM table
WHERE value = 0
```

because it's possible to have a record with the same order, but having `value > 0`. The only way I could find to write that query is that:

```
SELECT order
FROM table
GROUP BY order
HAVING SUM(COALESCE(value, 0)) = 0
```

But the query is very slow because of computing sum of very large amount of data.

Is there a way to write the query more efficiently?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might be faster to use `exists`:

```
select o.*
from orders o
where not exists (select 1
                  from table t
                  where t.order = o.order and t.value > 0
                 );
```

This assumes that you have a table with just the orders (called `orders` in the query).  Also, it will work best with an index on `table(order, value)`.

I also wonder if the following query would have acceptable performance with an index on `table(order, value desc)`

```
select t.*
from (select distinct on (order) t.*
      from table t
      order by order, value desc
     ) t
where value = 0;
```

The `distinct on` should use the index for the sorting, just taking the first row encountered.  The outer `where` would then filter these, but the two scans would probably be pretty fast.

Comment: I have index on the column. But when I try to write the subquery: `SELECT order FROM table WHERE order NOT IN (SELECT order FROM table WHERE value > 0)` the performance was even more terrible than of the query with the having clause. Couldn't you explain why?

Comment: @stella . . . I usually use `NOT EXISTS` rather than `NOT IN`, because it seems to be faster on most databases.  Here is a reference for Postgres 8.4 (http://explainextended.com/2009/09/16/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-postgresql/).